# What MOSFET is used in this waveshare e-paper display?

Tags: mosfet

I'm trying to create my own circuit around [this schematic](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/5/5b/1.54inch_e-Paper_Schematic.pdf). Its from a Waveshare 1,54inch E-paper display. I want to create my own board for this display, but I'm confused about what MOSFET this circuit uses.

It clearly lists that a Si1304BDL from Vishay Siliconix is used which is a N-channel enhancement mode MOSFET, but the symbol in the circuit diagram specifies a N-channel depletion mode MOSFET.

Here is an image of the MOSFET and the part number lines up with that of the datasheet.

[image: MOSFET on Waveshare E-paper development board]

I'm pretty sure it's a N-channel enhancement mode MOSFET, but I just want to be sure.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Very likely they just drew the circuit diagram wrong. It's much less likely they got the part number wrong, while the wrong symbol used can be just sloppiness/carelessness.

Comment: The symbol for MOSFETs is a bit of a strange one. While there are strict standards saying how to make it and what it means, people butcher it all the times - sometimes with more valid reasons than others. Seeing people draw the ''depletion mode'' symbol for enhancement mode is something I see a lot, and many don't even realize there is a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 'DMN3067LW' as replacement for the obsolete SI1304. It works fine on our selfmade boards.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody made an error in choosing the library symbol for an old obsolete part.

[image]